# change default sequence of billing information field in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal-commerce

I want to change the default sequence of billing information field .. we need that country field displayed after state field & require new field  phone no, company etc.

Can anyone tell me how can we add fields ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, so I hope you solved this already :) But if it's still a problem:

You can add fields to the customer profile type at Store => Customer Profiles. Select the tab "Profile types" and then "manage fields" (path: admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types).

When it comes to changing the order of the Address form components I'm not sure about what's the best way to go, but one *possible* way is certainly to use hook_form_alter to modify the #weight-property of the form components just like you would with any other form.

See this answer for instructions on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1311713/2622895